# Symfony2: What is a good pattern for preview form data before processing it?

Tags: forms, symfony

I've come to a common problem in the application I'm developing, there are three use cases described as:

> The object creation form must be followed by a preview page, where the
>   object is displayed in it's final state, with a button to finish the
>   creation, and a button to go back and modify it with the form.

I already have a typical base creation flow. A newAction that renders a newObject template with the form, which sends the data to a createAction that checks the data, creates the object, and redirects to the showObject action.

My rough idea is:
The newAction renders the newObject template, with a form that sends the data to a createAction, just as before. This createAction renders a previewObject template, with two buttons, which send the form to the createAction angain, where I can check which button got pressed where I can decide to display again the form with the object's data, or finish the cration flow and redirect to the showObject action.

My problems are:

1. There are three different buttons (Preview, Edit and Create) which should be displayed or hiddend depending on the templates (New, Preview).
2. The form in the previewObject template must be all hidden except for the buttons. Does the "preview" object has to be passed as a hidden form or is there another way I'm not seeing?

Do I need several forms to implement this feature? I'm trying to think a solution with one form and two actions, but I'm not sure it's enough.

This is a common use case, but I've not been able to find examples online.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question peaked my curiousity and I tried out a few different things.  Came up with an interesting way to handle it using a single form and a single action using `createFormBuilder` in a controller but I couldn't find a way to use the `createForm` with a `FormType` because you can't manipulate the form in the controller after calling `$form = $this->createForm(new NewsletterSignupType());`.

It feels a bit hacky but here it is, hopefully if nothing else it gives you some ideas.

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="newsletter_signup")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newsletterSignupAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->getNewsletterSignupForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $newButton    = $form->get('new');
            $editButton   = $form->get('edit');
            $createButton = $form->get('create');

            if ($newButton->isClicked()) {
                $form = $this->getNewsletterSignupForm($form->getData(), true);
            }

            if ($editButton->isClicked()) {
                /**
                 * We don't have to do anything here because we are just
                 * returning the original form with the submitted data attached
                 */
            }

            if ($createButton->isClicked()) {
                // User verified data and clicked "Create"
                $response = 'Thank you for signing up!';

                return new Response($response);
            }
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle creating the form and setting fields / buttons and data
     */
    protected function getNewsletterSignupForm($data = null, $previewMode = false)
    {
        $actionUrl = $this->generateUrl('newsletter_signup');

        $formBuilder             = $this->createFormBuilder($data);
        $fieldAttributes         = [];
        $newButtonAttributes     = [];
        $previewButtonAttributes = [];

        if ($previewMode) {
            $fieldAttributes['read_only'] = true;
            $newButtonAttributes['attr']  = ['hidden' => true];
        } else {
            $previewButtonAttributes['attr'] = ['hidden' => true];
        }

        $formBuilder->add('name', 'text', $fieldAttributes)
                    ->add('email_address', 'email', $fieldAttributes)
                    ->add('new', 'submit', $newButtonAttributes)
                    ->add('edit', 'submit', $previewButtonAttributes)
                    ->add('create', 'submit', $previewButtonAttributes);

        $formBuilder->setAction($actionUrl);

        $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
{# Acme:DemoBundle:newsletterSignup.html.twig #}

{% extends 'AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Great, no problem about being hacky, it works like a charm. Maybe it is possible to create a form class and pass the parameters in the constructor, or even as a service and inject them, I'm no expert also but this is a great start, thank you!